# mysql connect hang(remote connect)

Tags: mysql

Hi when I try to connect remote mysql

```
mysql -u root -p xxxx -h xxxx -P 80
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

then I hang at here

Does anyone knows how to slove this

Comment: It's very unlikely that something listening on port 80 speaks the MySQL protocol. I bet it's a web server.

Answer (score 0):

In your command you are specifyng port `80`. By default MySQL works on port `3306`.

Comment: there is a proxy between my client and real sql server

Comment: @user5966781 Then check that you are forwarding ports correctly.

Comment: this case is on my mac, but others can connect mysql successfully using the same way.

Comment: @user5966781 Did you really verify that such address is *not* a web server? It's as simple as loading it in a browser.